# How to Add Task View that Shows task completion in % ..?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, share

I want to create task view that task will be assigned to more than 2 people , and when ever one person completes the task of his part than % completed column will have to show the some % value like if 2 person in task involved than it have to show 50%.

Hope you guys/people understand my problem!

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge , you can develop share point designer workflow 2013 , and update the field value according to your business logic.

Suppose you have created task for 3 people. 
than you can manage workflow cursor and you can get task completed value on SharePoint Item changed event. you have to configure SharePoint workflow on item changed.

One task is completed you can do some calculation according to 100% and number of people for the task and set value to %percentage field.

I hope, you can get stuff.

Happy Coding:)